# Sonatype Nexus how to enable search inside an archive (zip)

Tags: search, metadata, nexus, sonatype

First, anyone aware a way to search inside an archive (such as zip, jar) artifact stored in Nexus? Or the right approach should be define additional metadata of each archive to enable the search?

We want to store all software installation packages inside Nexus and have a quick way to find them. To my understanding, the best way to store generic binary files in Nexus is using a Maven2 repository. Can we use any existing information like POM? What's the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed by Sonatype that "Nexus 2 does not support searching 'into a zip file.'.